# Long hash from string on iOS and Android

Tags: java, android, ios, hash

I have a requirement to hash strings to long on both iOS and Android. It is mandatory to have same results for same string on both platforms.

The code I'm using on iOS is:

```
+ (long long)hashString:(NSString *)stringToHash
{
     if (stringToHash.length == 0)
        return -1;

     //cr: resolve the warnings here
     const unsigned char* str = [stringToHash UTF8String];
     int hash = 5381;
     int c;
     while ((c = *str++)) hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
     bool isNegative = (hash < 0);
     hash = abs(hash);
     long long lhash = (long)hash;
     long long mask = 1;
     mask <<= 31;
     if (isNegative) lhash |= mask;
     return lhash;
}
```

For Android I'm using this code (c code, converted to Java):

```
public static long doHash(String value) {  
       if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
           return -1;
       }

       int hash = 5381;               
       for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
           hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + value.charAt(i);
       }     

       boolean isNegative = (hash < 0);
       hash = Math.abs(hash);

       long lHash = (long) hash;
       long mask = 1;       
       mask <<= 31;       
       if (isNegative) { lHash |= mask; }     

       return lHash;
 }
```

In general, everything works fine BUT sometimes in Android I have a problem, where I'm getting a different hash value for the same string.

For example:

```
            doHash("Saved Tap"); returns – 3598946179
            doHash("Saved Tap"); returns – 3433737033
```

I get these values from logs from devices out there... Not able to reproduce on devices I have.

Does anyone see any mistakes in the Java code that may cause this issue? Can it be Java version or Android version related?

Thanks,

Comment: Could it be that the strings aren't really the same? For example, they might contain some non-printable characters. I'd definitely print the chars individually to investigate this possibility.

Comment: @Cerovec, that's not possible. I can verify this as I send both the strings and their hashed values to my server.

Comment: This hash function provides poor randomization. For example, if ASCII codes of all chars from string are even, then hash result always will be odd. Regarding your question: I see only single suspicious place, using abs() function. This function converts data to double, and maybe somewhere changes output because of lost precision. I recommend try "if(hash < 0) hash = -hash".